# Preparing schedule for the Month - Day Based

Tags: pgfgantt

I would like to prepare a schedule (a plan) for a month on a daily basis describing the activities to be done. For example,

### Day 1

1. Activity 1
2. Activity 2
3. Activity 3
4. Activity 4

To achieve this, I resort to `pgfgnatt` package. I was able to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid=true]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{7} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Task 2}{3}{7}
\ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Milestone}{7}
\ganttnewline
\ganttbar{Final Task}{8}{12}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, How do I increase the width of the day column to write text into it. For example, Learning is a general activity. On Day 1, - Java, On Day 2, - LaTeX, etc.. Or, is there any other efficient way to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: can you use any of the solutions described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217834/how-to-create-a-timeline-with-latex)?

Comment: @AndyClifton can the timeline be made vertical?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe you could work a bit on your question? Could you sketch out with pen and paper what you are looking for?

Comment: @AndyClifton please see the edit